# Tagging people who aren't on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos, facebook-tags

I uploaded a collection of photos with a person I wasn't able to find on Facebook. Is there a way to enter his/her name? It's not a tag in the photo itself, but in the part where you specify "who you are with".